# Author Tools for Classroom Material?

Tags: authoring

I'm interested in putting a whole bunch of classroom material online.  This material ranges from accounting classes to yoga.  I would like to find a simple to use authoring tool that the people who teach the classes can use to put the material online.  In other words, I do not want a tool that requires a developer.  A person who knows the subject matter and is willing to read the manual should be able to put their material online.

At minimum, this tool should allow for text and multi-media to be chained together in a logical form and it should allow quizzes to be created and graded.  Even better would be for the tool to have some "smarts" so that subject areas which the student does not understand can be drilled.  Even better would be for the tool to have ecommerce built in so that the instructors can charge for the classes.

Are there any such tools?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some skills needed to set up, but [moodle](http://moodle.org/) might be what you're looking for - its a FOSS equivilent of blackboard

Comment: If this question were posted now, I'd recommend Canvas (http://instructure.com/), which is dual-licensed as both commercial proprietary software and open-source software.